# Postgres JSONB date range search

Tags: postgresql-performance

I have a JSONB object with many elements, one of which is a date.  The following query is now very slow with millions of rows in my table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE obj->>'dob' BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-01'.
```

How can I improve performance on this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an index on the column. However casting strings to dates for an index isn't straightforward, as the conversion isn't recognized as "immutable" by Postgres (although it is).

With a little workaround, this can be done though:

```
create function dob(p_value jsonb)
returns date 
as
$$
  select (p_value ->> 'dob')::date;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can create an index:

```
create index on the_table ( (dob(obj)) );
```

And use the function in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table 
WHERE dob(obj) BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you